# Combining Spring security and JSF 2 : Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2, spring-security

i am trying to integrate JSF2 and spring security, after solving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536355/integrating-spring-security-with-jsf-2) error (which was a version mismatch  problem) now i am getting a new error. what is wrong with this configuration?

i have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122939/spring-error-creating-bean-with-name-datasource-defined-in-servletcontext-res) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558250/error-creating-bean-with-name-datasource-defined-in-servletcontext-resource) and some more, but none of them solved my problem

i am using :

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <springsecurity.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <jetty.version>8.1.7.v20120910</jetty.version>
</properties>
```

spring-database.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/azraspina" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and this is spring-security.xml :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint ">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.xhtml" />
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationProcessingFilter" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />


    <beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler"
            ref="failureHandler" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            ref="successHandler" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="successHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index.xhtml" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="failureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/index.xhtml" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/index.xhtml" />
        <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="
                    select username,password, enabled 
                    from users where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="
                    select u.username, r.authority from users u, roles r, user_roles ur 
                    where u.user_id = ur.user_id and r.role_id = ur.role_id and u.username =?    " />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


</beans:beans>
```

and part of stacktrace :

```
ct 23, 2013 3:24:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/spring-database.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL
    at org.springframework.expression.TypedValue.<clinit>(TypedValue.java:32)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.setRootObject(StandardEvaluationContext.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.<init>(StandardEvaluationContext.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:183)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED .

the trick was to add this dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

it seems easy now :D